# The -q option of bsdtar

Tags: bash, bsdtar

I ran across the following code in a bash script.

```
# See if bsdtar can recognize the file
if bsdtar -tf "$file" -q '*' &>/dev/null; then
   cmd="bsdtar"
else
continue
```

what did the '-q' option mean? I did not find any information in the help message of bsdtar command.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From the bsdtar [man page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/BSDTAR/):

> ```
> -q (--fast-read)
>      (x and t mode only) Extract or list only the first archive entry
>      that matches each pattern or filename operand.  Exit as soon as
>      each specified pattern or filename has been matched.  By default,
>      the archive is always read to the very end, since there can be
>      multiple entries with the same name and, by convention, later
>      entries overwrite earlier entries.  This option is provided as a
>      performance optimization.
> ```